# Mule ESB Server 3.6.1 - HTTP Component URI Params via GET method to Java Component

Tags: mule

I am new to Mule ESB... Using Anypoint Studio, how will I be able to access a HTTP GET params in a Java Component? An example would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access inbound properties as follows:

```
import java.util.Map;

import org.mule.api.MuleEventContext;
import org.mule.api.MuleMessage;
import org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable;

public class MyComponent implements Callable{

@Override
public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
    MuleMessage message = eventContext.getMessage();

    Map uriParams = message.getInboundProperty("http.uri.params");
    String name = (String) uriParams.get("name");

    ...
}

}
```

Where 'name' is the name of the URI param you want to access. If you want to access other inbound properties, replace 'http.uri.params' with the inbound property you want to access. HTH

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It makes sense now. However, I get the warning "Map cannot be resolved" and "message cannot be resolved". What's missing?

Comment: You need to import map (java.util.Map) and you also need to get the current message from the event context.  I've modified my answer to include the full example code.